# Pass additional arguments to an executable

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I run `sharelatex` via docker and need it to use the `-shell-escape` flag (for some packages (minted)) while compiling. `sharelatex` makes a call like `pdflatex some arguments` to run `pdflatex`. I tried the last answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109979/sharelatex-compilation-flags/)

so i renamed `pdflatex` to `pdflatex_orig` and created this script:

```
#! /bin/sh
pdflatex_orig -shell-escape
```

to run the real `pdflatex` with the flag.

The problem is that the arguments are not passed. So if I run `pdflatex --v` the interactive shell start. If I run `pdflatex_orig --v` it gives me some information about the version.

So, is there a way to "pipe" the parameters to the original script + my shell-escape flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex_orig -shell-escape "$@"
```